# What are all the protips?

Tags: hyper-princess-pitch

In [Hyper Princess Pitch](http://www.remar.se/daniel/pitch.php), what are all the protips you unlock by beating the game in the various difficulty levels? The best I can do is Combat Lady, but I want to know what the rest of them are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Counter/piledriver: Press ↑↓←→ or ↑↓→← when not firing. Land on an X to get hidden powerups
- Secret level/true ending: Counter the giant rainbow laser
- Summon Goddess (once per game): Press ↑↑↓↓←→←→ when not firing
- Cheat codes (enter during play): RGIOSA RGCATS RGFILL RGGIVE RGCELL RGWISH RGXCES
- ReallyJoel's mom difficulty: Hold → on the difficulty selection screen for ten seconds

Comment: Looks good to me! Joel's mom must be a hardcore lady.